# Passing a function into a model default value in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I want the default values of a model to call a function like so:

```
class Entities.Cart extends Backbone.Model
 defaults: =>
   tip:             0
   useStoreCredit:  @hasCredit()

 hasCredit: =>
   if @get('credit') > 0
     true
   else
     false
```

I know defaults can be defined as a function [as referenced in the Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) and [in the Marionette docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.behavior.md#defaults). But neither of those documents reference calling a function in the defaults hash. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that but it isn't a great idea. The problem is that there's no guarantee about the state of `@` when the `defaults` function is called. The [docs only say](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults):

> The **defaults** hash (or function) can be used to specify the default attributes for your model. When creating an instance of the model, any unspecified attributes will be set to their default value.

There's nothing in there that says that `@attributes` will have anything in it when `defaults` is called so `@get('credit')` may or may not return a useful value. If you check the current behavior:

```
class M extends Backbone.Model
  defaults: ->
    console.log @toJSON()
    a: 'b'

m  = new M
mm = new M(a: 'c')
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6tjLuhrn/)

you'll see that `@attributes` is empty when `defaults` is called. This even makes sense: you grab the defaults, merge in the attributes from the constructor call, and then set up `@attributes`; of course, these orders also make sense:

- Set up `@attributes` with the defaults, then merge in the constructor arguments.
- Set `@attributes` to the constructor arguments, then call `defaults` to get values for unspecified attributes.

Basically, you can't depend on `@` being in any particular state when `defaults` is called.

However, there's no reason to have `useStoreCredit` as a static attribute. You can provide your own `toJSON` implementation to compute it as needed:

```
toJSON: ->
  h = _(@attributes).clone() # This is the standard toJSON
  h.useStoreCredit = @get('credit') > 0
  h
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to the last part of your answer. Since `useStoreCredit` needs to be a boolean I kept the `default: useStoreCredit: false` and then I'm going to use `useStoreCredit` as a static attribute. Thanks!